# sqoop - job failure during data import

Tags: hdfs, sqoop

what will happen incase sqoop fails between large data import job. Will it copy  some of the data onto hdfs before the job failure occured or it will not copy anything at all?

Answer (score 0):

In a case where you are running the job with `--num-mapper` more than 1, when some numbers of map gets successful, one failed at some point and rest of the RUNNING maps will get killed.

Lets say you ran using 4 mapper:

- MAP-1: Success
- MAP-2: Success
- MAP-3: Killed because of MAP-4 failure
- MAP-4: Failed because of some reason

You will have data for MAP-1 & MAP-2 in `--target-dir`.

---

If you have a hive table on top of your location and if you are using [`HCatalog`](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_sqoop_hcatalog_integration) option to import data into HDFS. Then hive creates `.staging` directory inside table location.

After all Maps got success then hive rename the staging directory to actual one.

In this case if your job fails HCatalog removes the staging directory.